# using sed or grep to extract word

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I get only white space when I try to extract the ID by code:

```
grep "latest" sometextfile | sed 's/.*latest\([\s*]*\).*/\1/'
```

```
REPO                                              SAL                  ID            CREATED             SIZE
asdasfdg.dshgs.asd:54000/my-thing                       latest   c5521d9803e7        asdfa days ago          asdfafd.ad
```

Code:

```
grep "latest" sometextfile | sed 's/.*latest\([\s*]*\).*/\1/'
```

The out put from command above should be the ID: `c5521d9803e7`.

What is missing at the sed command above?

Comment: With awk: `awk '$2=="latest"{print $3}' file`

Comment: Although `\s` is fine with GNU `sed`, what you are trying to capture here is *optional whitespaces*, hence what you see on screen is blank.

Comment: If `sed` should be the answer this could be it `sed -E 's/latest\s*(\S+).*|./\1/g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a simple `awk` might work:

```
awk '/latest/{ print $3 }' file
```

See [this online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/2ZjNwR). It finds a line with `latest` in it and prints Field 3 contents.

However, following your original logic, you may use `sed` alone to extract that piece of string after `latest`:

```
sed -n '/[[:space:]]latest[[:space:]]/s/.*latest[[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]]*\).*/\1/p' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/nWIfFp)

**Details**

- `/[[:space:]]latest[[:space:]]/` - finds the line with whitespace+`latest`+whitespace
- `s/.*latest[[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]]*\).*/\1/p` - finds and replaces with Group 1 contents:

  - `.*latest` - any  0+ chars up to the last occurrence of `latest`
  - `[[:space:]]*` - 0 or more whitespaces
  - `\([^[:space:]]*\)` - Group 1: any 0 or more non-whitespace chars
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars to the end of the line

The `-n` option suppresses line output and `p` only shows the substitution result.

Comment: I'll use awk. Thank you!